# Setup Popover in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, popover

I'm learning Bootstrap via video instruction. We're now on Popovers and Tooltips but the instruction video is using an older version of Bootstrap, I'm using Bootstrap v5.0.x; how do I include the third-party library, download the popover , and manually enable popover. I have read the Bootstrap v5 documentation, I still don't understand what steps to take. Please speak plainly as I am new to computer lingo.

The following is code I'm working on.  Is this what you were asking for @kmoser?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>TEST Modals, Popovers, & Tootips</title>  <!-- getbootstrap.com -->
    
  </head>    
  <body>
      
                <!-- Modal Trigger Button -->      
      <button type="button" class="name-button btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-name="Joe">Email Joe</button>
      
                  <button type="button" class="name-button btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-name="Phil">Email Phil</button>
      
            <button type="button" class="name-button btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-name="Nicki">Email Nicki</button>
    
      
                   <!-- The Modal Itself  -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
                   
            <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

                          <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

                         <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
      
       <script type="text/javascript">
          
          $(".name-button").click(function (event) {
               $('.modal-header h5.modal-title').html("New message to " + $(this).attr('data-name'));
              
           });           
                    
       </script>
      
  </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: The [Bootstrap 5 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) describes how to download Popper.js as well as how to [initialize all popovers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/#example-enable-popovers-everywhere).

Comment: This where I have been having difficulty, and why I mention I am a "lay person", I've already visited that page.  I don't understand what to do; how do I, "include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js"........  I really need help here,,,,,

Comment: Those pages give you examples of the `<script>` tags you need. Have you tried that? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67496514/edit) to show us what you have written so far.

Comment: @kmoser I have no idea how to get started using popover, I want to add popovers to my code via Bootstrap. I just need to know how to do that.   I have to wait 90 minutes to post another question....

Comment: If you open your browser's console you will see that there is an error. You are attempting to use jQuery code but you have not imported jQuery. You need to add something like this to the bottom of the `<head>` section: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`.

Comment: Thank you so much @kmoser, I really appreciate your help......      I don't see where I can vote for you.........

Comment: If my comment helped fix your problem, I can post it as an answer and you can accept it and/or upvote it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setup Popover in Bootstrap v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497111/setup-popover-in-bootstrap-v5)